# What are the transcripts (about 5 lines) of this Jimmy Kimmel Live show?

Tags: listening

I would like to know what are the transcripts at 00:40~00:49, 01:51~01:54 and 04:51~04:53 of this Jimmy Kimmel Live show(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75b2hTl2T2E).

These are what I heard:

00:40~00:49
And we mixed up a very special concoction
of these loser organic juices that they appear to be
but we used Fun Dip instead
that's the ? stick

01:51~01:54
yeah, like little refreshing, 
like you dip into a pool of juice

04:51~04:53
Are you gonna take the kale, obviously?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the question. I like it. But I still can't figure out what Cold Pressed Juice is. What is "Cold Pressed Juice"?

Comment: scale it one to ten, 1 being 'skittles', 10 being actual real fruit. Where does it fall, "this is nine" the man said. Please correct if it it wrong.

Comment: I would like to know what A, B and C mean.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a transcription service

Answer (score 1):

> 00:40-00:49: And we mixed up a very special concoction. Okay, so those are organic juices, err... They appear to be... But we used Fun Dip, instead. That's the... We eat 'em with a stick...

(This candy is eaten by dipping the stick that comes with the packet into the sherbet)

> 01:51-01:54: Yeah! Like a little refreshing, like, little dip into a pool of juice.

(Reworded to make more sense: "It's like a little refreshing dip into a pool of juice")

> 04:51-04:53: Are you getting the kale, obviously?

(As in: "You can taste the [kale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kale), I assume?")